# Emptying array and clearing all intervals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to empty or reset an array, as you can see below. I have two `<li>` each is set to 0. Once the first `<li>` reaches to 5 I want it to stop incrementing, and once the second `<li>` reaches 10 I also want it to stop incrementing, this is done by using setInterval function each has their own variable dynamic name `intervals[number] = seInterval()`.

By default I want to call get_default() function so that it will start incrementing. As you can see below, once the second `<li>` is done, I want to alert the value inside `intervals` array. At first, it is giving me "1,2", then on second click, "6,7", then on third click "9,10" and so on.

My question is, how come it is not giving me a value of `"0,1"` since those are the values that I am passing `get_result(0); get_result(1);` and is there a right way to clear or reset all intervals that are running once a user click the reset button?

```js
var intervals = [];

function get_result(number) {
  clearInterval(intervals[number]);
  intervals[number] = setInterval(function() {

    var total_count = parseInt($('ul li:eq(' + number + ')').html());
    var increment = total_count + 1;

    $('ul li:eq(' + number + ')').html(increment);

    if (number == 0 && increment == 5) {
      clearInterval(intervals[number]);
    }

    if (number == 1 && increment == 10) {
      clearInterval(intervals[number]);
      console.log(intervals);
    }
  }, 1000);

}

//Default
function get_default() {
  get_result(0);
  get_result(1);
}

//Run on default
get_default();


$('input').click(function() {
  //Reset
  intervals = [];
  $('li').html(0);
  get_default();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Reset">
```

Comment: since you `intervals = [];` before calling get_default in the click handler, how can `clearInterval(intervals[number]);` work?

Comment: as for the console log ... it's outputting the "interval ID", not the number you passed in

Comment: So how do you use these interval IDs so that all intervals will be cleared  before calling get_default() function again?

Comment: don't clear the intervals array before calling get_default/get_result

Comment: What if the other intervals are not yet finished before executing get_default? This is just for sample purpose, that's why I only put 2, but what if you have 10 of these intervals running?

Comment: then clearing the array is what you DONT want to do anyway - so, all good

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) setTimeout returns a numeric value.

> The returned intervalID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value can be passed to WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval() to cancel the timeout.

On running the code snippet we see the intervalID of the setTimeout being logged out from the array.

Here in my snippet i have changed intervals data type to object, with this i am able to store the get_result argument as key and the intervalID as value.

Hoping this will helps you out.

```js
var intervals = {};

function get_result(number) {
  clearInterval(intervals[number]);
  intervals[number] = setInterval(function() {

    var total_count = parseInt($('ul li:eq(' + number + ')').html());
    var increment = total_count + 1;

    $('ul li:eq(' + number + ')').html(increment);

    if (number == 0 && increment == 5) {
      clearInterval(intervals[number]);
    }

    if (number == 1 && increment == 10) {
      clearInterval(intervals[number]);
      console.log(intervals);
    }
  }, 1000);

}

//Default
function get_default() {
  get_result(0);
  get_result(1);
}

//Run on default
get_default();


$('input').click(function() {
  //Reset
  intervals = {};
  $('li').html(0);
  get_default();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Reset">
```

Comment: I didn't help at all, the intervals are still running and not being cleared out